# Core.js not found, but it's actually there in node modules. Meteor client is fine. Ionic is broken.

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, meteor, npm

The errors occurs when importing the meteor-client.js. When loading ecmascript-runtime-client, it suggested: The core-js npm package could not be found in your node_modules directory. Please run the following command to install it: meteor npm install --save core-js.
Actually, I did install it on both meteor's node_modules and ionic's node_modules.I launched the meteor client, it is fine. While in ionic, the compile process goes well, but with the error displayed in the browser. I was stuck there for 3 days, I deep dived into src. I am still not sure whether it came from webpack or meteor-client-bundler or anything else. I surfed and found no any answer in online resources.

The error stack:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'core-js/modules/es7.object.get-own-property-descriptors'
at makeMissingError (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:125256:14)
at Module.require (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:125275:19)
at _require (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:125291:25)
at modern.js (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:128255:15)
at fileEvaluate (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:125369:9)
at Module.require (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:125272:16)
at _require (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:125291:25)
at http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:128275:18
at Object. (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:128279:3)
at Object.defineProperty.value (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:214805:30)
```

I made this [repo](https://github.com/dc165015/issue) and [issue](https://github.com/Urigo/angular-meteor/issues/1941)

Please help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the same error by adding `"npmPackages": [ "core-js", "@babel/runtime@7.0.0-beta.55" ]` to your meteor-client's config json file (default is `meteor-client.config.json`).

I don't know exactly why, but works.

Comment: It is caused by  meteor-client-bundler which couldn't work correctly.